# VBA & Function Operator When Passing to Win32

Tags: vba

The VBA code snippet shown below works great (thanks to Google) for enumerating all open windows via Win32. I have omitted the EnumCallBack() function for brevity.

The question I have is that the & operator appears after a numeric constant in the EnumWindows call. I know that EnumWindows expects a pointer as the 2nd argument, so I am inferring that the & operator after a constant is passing the address of the constant to Win32. I scoured the web a bit and could not find any documentation on this. Just wanted to verify my hunch. I expect the & would pass the address of a VBA custom Type..End Type as well?

```
Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Boolean
Private ProcWinHandle As Long
Private ProcessHandle As Long

Public Function GetProcessWindowHandle(ProcID As Long) As Long
    ProcessHandle = ProcID
    ProcWinHandle = 0
    Dim retval As Long
    retval = EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumCallBack, 0&)
    GetProcessWindowHandle = ProcWinHandle
End Function
```

Comment: For address related confusion read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101(v=vs.84).aspx, for the character suffix in variables read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` is the short form for the `Long` type. `Dim Var as Long` and `Dim var&` are equivalent. You can also see the `EnumWindows` function takes a `Long` as its second parameter.

Here's a listing of the common types with their abbreviation.

```
Public Sub WhichType()
    Dim VarInteger%
    Dim VarLong&
    Dim VarSingle!
    Dim VarDouble#
    Dim VarCurrency@
    Dim VarString$

    'Show the type
    Debug.Print TypeName(VarInteger)
    Debug.Print TypeName(VarLong)
    Debug.Print TypeName(VarSingle)
    Debug.Print TypeName(VarDouble)
    Debug.Print TypeName(VarCurrency)
    Debug.Print TypeName(VarString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I was WAY off... Jeff